# Maven Release Plugin - Access denied

Tags: git, maven, release, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to configure Maven Release Plugin for a multi model project which has the following modules: parent, Model, WebApplication, WebServices.

I've made the plugin work for a simple project as a test, but for this project I've not been able to.

parent\pom.xml

```
     ....
        <version>2.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        .....
        <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>release</id>
                <url>file://git.comapany.ro/dragos.geornoiu/test.git</url>
            </repository>
        </distributionManagement>
        <scm>connection>scm:git:git@git.company.ro:dragos.geornoiu/test.git</connection></scm>
   ....
   <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
    ....
    </plugins>
```

The oher modules take the version from the parent pom:

```
<parent>
        ...
        <version>2.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I run mvn release:prepare from the parent module.

The plugin asks for the new versions of each module and the new version for development. It changes the version from 2.4.1-SNAPSHOT to 2.4.1, creates a local tag, but stops there. The tag isn't pushed and the development version isn't changed to 2.4.2-SNPASHOT.

```
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Access denied.
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
```

I am connecting with ssh to the remote and have tested commit, push and creating a tag from the parent module, all of them work just fine (since I am not getting a permission denied or something similar, I don't think this is a problem). Also, the plugin manages to make a push after changing the version to 2.4.1 (removing SNAPSHOT).

I've tried looking with -X parameter, but cant' figure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The user which runs the mvn release does not have permission to push to the git repo, maybe the ssh keys are not set up.  Try doing it from the command line first, if you look at the log it will show you the exact git command it is trying to execute,

Comment: @EssexBoy The plugin manages to make a push, changing the version on the repo from 2.4.1-SNPASHOT to 2.4.1. The mvn release:prepare command is run from the command line and after the error occurs I am able to make a "git push --tags" and the created tag is pushed to the repo.

Comment: That is not what your error message says??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by reading this article - [MAVEN-RELEASE-PLUGIN "UNABLE TO TAG SCM" ISSUE AND SOLUTION](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/maven_release_plugin_unable_to).

> In case the modules are located on the same level as the pom-project
>   and need to be referenced
>
> …you will get a misleading error message:
>
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to tag
>   SCM
>
> Provider message: The git-push command failed.
>
> Command output:
>   ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

After moving the Model, WebApplication, WebServices modules into the parent and changing the paths in each pom.xml, the mvn release:prepare command executed succesfully.